# Google Drive API returns 500 Internal Server Error when exporting large documents

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-ruby-client

I was trying to export(programmatically download from google drive) a slides document that is larger than 10MB in PDF format and encountered `Error - #<Google::Apis::ServerError: Server error>`.

I am using Google API ruby client and there is no specification on why this can happen. Documents that are <10MB when downloaded as PDF manually works fine when exported programmatically.

The method I use to export files is

`@service.export_file(id, 'application/pdf', download_dest: StringIO.new).string`,

`@service` is a `Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService` object.

Comment: If a download fails your going to have to start again there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: It fails on every single attempt. I don't think implementing any backoffs can save it.